# When and how to use Sonic Bombs in Monster Hunter?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations-ultimate

For some monsters I know I can use sonic bombs whilst they are underground. But when else can I utilize them?
General tips as well as specific for monster hunter generations ultimate are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Burrow Monsters**

They can be forced to surface and it flips them over.  Only works when out of rage.

2. **Hearing Sensitive Monsters**

Some monsters can be stunned, like Lagombi and Kut-Ku.

3. **Hermitaur**

The crabs in defensive stance can be knocked out of that.

4. **Kecha Wacha**

When he's climbing around you can knock him down.

5. **Nakarkos**

In his second form, and he's flailing his arms with skeleton heads, a sonic bomb will make him smash himself in the head.  (Works limited times.)

6. **Flying small monsters**

In Coal Hearted, the sonic bomb will ground the flying Remobras so you can mine undisturbed.

**Bonus**: the sonic bomb also affects Nargacuga, but it only instantly puts it into rage mode.   Why would you do that?  Because of the Challenger armor skill.

Answer (score 1):

Most Monsters that burrow can be sonic bombed so they surface again. This usually doesn't work when they are enraged.
The crabs can be sonic bombed when they are guarding so they flinch for a moment.

Use this chart for more info :
https://pm1.narvii.com/6436/b0838ee5acfda18d2325ef1e6ca715df8a7d2825_hq.jpg